# setting 2D array last element too NULL is deleting the first element

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, null

So I was working on my function strsplit (its supposed to work similar to strtok) and I was having an issue where the first element was being essentially bzero-ed. I narrowed it down to the fact that I set the last pointer to NULL after I populated the array. I have no idea why it was doing this and I can't find an answer. Before you mention my code is broken, yes I know, I just would like to know why its doing this before finishing it.

```
tab[ft_countforstrings(c, (char *)s) + 1] = NULL; //this is the line that goes under the malloc line

char    **ft_strsplit(char const *s, char c)
{
    char    **tab;
    int     x;
    int     y;
    int     tabcount;

    if (s == NULL || *s == 0) //check for bad strings
        return (NULL);
    printf("start, not NULL\n");
    printf("%p\n", s);
    tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (ft_countforstrings(c, (char *)s) + 1)); // when put after this line it works fine.
    tabcount = 0;
    y = 0;
    x = 0;
    while (s[x])
    {
        printf("%s %i %i %i\n", s, x, y, x - y);
        y = s[x] == c && s[x + 1] == c ? y - 1 : y;
        if (s[x] == c)
        {
            printf("in loop\n");
            printf("%s %i %i %i\n", s, x, y, x - y);
            tab[tabcount++] = ft_strsub(s, x - y, y);
            printf("%s %s\n", tab[tabcount - 1], ft_strsub(s, x - y, y));
            y = -1;
        }
        y++;
        x++;
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    printf("%s %i\n", tab[0], tabcount);
    tab[tabcount++] = ft_strsub(s, x - y, y);
    printf("%s %i - just before\n", tab[0], tabcount);
    tab[tabcount] = NULL; //<- this is the problem line right here, its fixed when I put it right after mallocing the 
    printf("%s %i - after last one is NULL\n", tab[0], tabcount);
    x = 0;
    printf("\n\nsplit out:\n");
    while (tab[x] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s| - |%p| - |%i\n", tab[x], tab[x], tab[x][0]);
        x++;
    }
    return (tab);
}
```

the difference in out put goes from

before fix:

```
function call: ft_strsplit("he*l*l*of", '*');
output :
| - |0x7f8b0a402780| - |0
l| - |0x7f8b0a4027a0| - |108
l| - |0x7f8b0a4027c0| - |108
of| - |0x7f8b0a4027e0| - |111
```

after fix:

```
function call: ft_strsplit("he*l*l*of", '*');
output :
he| - |0x7f92ffc02780| - |104
l| - |0x7f92ffc027a0| - |108
l| - |0x7f92ffc027c0| - |108
of| - |0x7f92ffc027e0| - |111
```

If someone could please explain why this is that would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: What are all those `ft` functions? What are they doing? What is the meaning of the single assignment above the `ft_strsplit` function? Will `tabcount` always be less than `ft_countforstrings(c, (char *)s) + 1`? And have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger?

Comment: Where is the 2D array? All I see is a 1D array of pointers. What does `ft_strsub` do, does it allocate memory?

Comment: for context, I am writing a library called libft. It's supposed to be mimic functions from string.h and stdlib.h. Yes, a 2d array is just an array of pointers, I just used malloc to make it dynamic. also I meant to delete that line at the top, but its the line that was breaking everything. I did some more testing and found that it was now deleting the index with NULL in it however.

Comment: In the "line that goes under the malloc", the index is the same as the number of items allocated, which means it's one beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: Please show `ft_countforstrings`. I guess it has an off-by-one error. For example, your string `"he*l*l*of"` has three asterisks, but splitting it yields four substrings plus one for the ´NULL` sentinel is five. I guess you just allocate four.

Comment: I was just talking with one of my friends, it was mallocing one too small. countfotstrings was returning the number of delimiters, not the number of strings